# Template parse issue nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, smarty

I'm quite new to NodeJS , i trying to get a solution for issue facing on my node project

issue is when hitting many users on site showing one user data to another user screen

seems like issue with template parsing  , using nsmarty to   render template

**app.js**

```
var app = express();
var configure = require('./configure');
//default setters
config = configure.app();
$arr = {
  config : config
}
```

**home.js (route file[controller])**

```
$arr['usercorp'] = results[4][0][0];
 $arr['ses_id'] = req.body.sess_id;
 $arr['us_id'] = req.body.id;

template.loadTemplate(req,res,$arr);
```

**template.js**

```
exports.loadTemplate = function(req,res,arr)
{
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=UTF-8');
         nsmarty.clearCache(arr.file); 

         stream = nsmarty.assign(arr.file,arr);

    stream.pipe(res);
}
```

Let me know if need more details

Thanks in advance